# Is it necessary to implement a sensing resistor plus pre-amp with Faraday cage on a PCB if I would like to have the range about 10nA measurement?

Tags: current, amplifier, adc, measurement, faraday-cage

I put a 60 kΩ sensing resistor plus low-bias current amplifier with a gain of 500 into an aluminium bag and tied it to AGND for EMI shielding. The second stage is an ADS1256 24-bit ADC. The purpose is to try to get a lower noise level during extremely low current measurements. I would like to implement it all on a PCB. What kind of Faraday cage is suitable for this?